# Precompile templates using Gulp

Tags: gulp, precompile

I want to precompile a template using Gulp, for Mustache, Liquid or HandleBars or any template language with nice `{{ }}` syntax.

I want it to run in a browser without any dependency. Is there any library that could help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [gulp-template](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-template), I still would want an alternative for this one. I used interpolate and evaluate configurations to make more pretty the syntax:

```
    {
        interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
        evaluate: /\{%(.+?)%\}/g
    }
```

But I'm using JavaScript syntax with it. As an alternative I can use [Nunjuncks](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/) but I need to put a little runner in the browser for the precompiled templates get to work.